# Using Join, Group By, Having and Where clause in the same query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables named as S1 and S2. I have a common column i.e. ID. The same ID can have number of records in S2. Now I want to retrieve only one record from S2 along with other records in S1. The record from S2 can be null also. I framed the query like this.

```
SELECT     
    [ID], [C], [ST], [AS], [CD], [SS], [SD],
FROM      
    [dbo].[S1] 
WHERE
    SD IN (SELECT MAX(SD) 
           FROM S1 (nolock) 
           WHERE SID = 45 AND SS != 7 
           GROUP BY AS)
```

This is returning only the records from S1 table. Now I want to innner join this with the second table S2 to get the records which are having ID in the above result and LogType should be 2. It can return null also for this record.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   [ID] ,
                        [C] ,
                        [ST] ,
                        [AS] ,
                        [CD] ,
                        [SS] ,
                        [SD]
               FROM     [dbo].[S1]
               WHERE    SD IN ( SELECT  MAX(SD)
                                FROM    S1 (NOLOCK)
                                WHERE   [SID] = 45
                                        AND SS <> 7
                                GROUP BY [AS] )
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte c
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      [dbo].[S2]
                          WHERE     ID = c.ID
                                    AND LogType = 2
                        ) oa
```

Comment: How can I write this query as Stored Procedure?